# Can a statistician become an actuarial consultant without pursuing another degree?

Tags: certification

I have a Ph.D. in statistics and am working at a university. I plan to become a consultant at an insurance company because I found that a statistician has fewer work opportunities than an actuarial certificate holder. Also, I found that actuarial science is mainly based on statistics, mathematics, and finance. I am great with math and statistics, but I need to improve with finance; however, I will build my skills on this topic.

My question is, can a statistician become an actuarial consultant or not? To become an actuarial consultant, must I get a bachelor's and master's degree in actuarial science? I am working at a university in the Middle East, but I would like to move to other companies that focus on insurance.

Comment: In which country is this? The rules can differ per country.

Comment: In the US the actuarial exams lead to certification. A degree in math (maybe statistics) gives you a pass on the first couple of exams (note: very old experience with this) but you still need to take the others. You don't, or didn't, need any degree in actuarial science. Any large insurance company should have someone who can give you details and they will be country specific.

Comment: And, an actuarial certificate in one country may not be transferrable to another. It seems unlikely to me that it would, actually. A place like the EU might have general rules, of course across countries.

Comment: @Buffy, Thank you for your comment. So much appreciated.

Comment: Actuaries are certified by examinations in the US. Anyone can call themselves an actuary, but it is better to have taken and passed the exams. In Canada, actuaries are licensed and only people who have a license can use the title. You should consider taking the exams.

Comment: @DavidSmith Thank you so much. I appreciate your comment.